# Plotly px.choropleth not drawing data from json file

Tags: python, json, geojson, plotly-python

I have a CSV file with the following structure

`cardodb_id,CONCELHO,LAT,LONG,DATA,INC 225,Abrantes,39.466667,-8.2,2020-03-25,1000`

And a Json file with the following structure:

`{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [ {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-8.163874,39.626553],[-8.164286,39.626686],[-8.165384,39.626633],*(more coordinates' pairs)*,[-8.163874,39.626553]]]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":225,"id_2":225,"id_1":16,"id_0":182,"varname_2":null,"nl_name_2":null,"engtype_2":"Municipality","type_2":"Concelho","name_2":"Abrantes","name_1":"Santarém","name_0":"Portugal","iso":"PRT","split_id":"1"}} ]}`

**Both the CSV and the json file here are part of a larger set but this will do as an example**

**My code is as follows**

```
import json
with open('abrantes.json') as json_file:
    abr = json.load(json_file)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("abrantes.csv")

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=abr, locations='cardodb_id', color='INC',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 5000),
                           labels={'INC':'Incidência'}
                          )

fig.show()
```

The end result is an empty map with the scale from 0 to 5000 on the right side, when I was expecting the polygon to be filled with the color correspondent to "INC", i.e., "1000".

**What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for all the help you can provide.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a map, px.choropleth() must match IDs of your dataframe with IDs of your GeoJSON.
With the parameter `locations` you specify the column with the IDs in your dataframe.
What you are missing is the parameter `featureidkey` to  specify the same IDs in the GeoJSON. Alternatively, you can omit `featureidkey`  but then the features in your GeoJSON need a parameter `id`.

Then you have to pay attention to spelling. Your csv file has a column `cardodb_id`, your GeoJSON a parameter `cartodb_id`.

And since the polygon you provided is quite small, it is not visible on a world map. Thus, I recommend to add `fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")` to zoom the map to the area of interest.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

with open('abrantes.json') as json_file:
    abr = json.load(json_file)

df = pd.read_csv("abrantes.csv")

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=abr, locations='cardodb_id', color='INC',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           featureidkey="properties.cartodb_id",
                           range_color=(0, 5000),
                           labels={'INC':'Incidência'}
                          )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")                        
fig.show()
```